# Vim/Gvim default file type on Windows

Tags: windows, vim

On windows 7, when I edit mark down files (.mdwn) and try to open tab (:tabnew but via the menu), the default file type is set to HTML (*.html or *.htm).  There's a drop down to set it to all files (*.*) but I'd like that as a default.

In the *nix world this is trivial, but how do you do in the Windows world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the Markdown *filetype plugin* includes the HTML one, and that sets the *browse filter*. To modify that, add the following to `~\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\markdown.vim`:

```
if has("gui_win32")
    let  b:browsefilter="Markdown Files (*.mdwm)\t*.mdwn\n"
endif
```

Comment: +1, accepted!  Thank you.  I did edit you post to make it windows specific instead of *nix specific since my question was about windows.